# Sefer Matei Efraim on Noach

Tags: product-recommendation, parashat-noach, mabul

I was told once by an older Rabbi about 10 years ago, how he read a sefer 30 years ago that taught that the Dor Ha-Mabul (the generation of the flood)  had what seemed to be technology that let them fly like we have airplanes, other technology that made them communicate over huge distances like our telephones, etc.

He said that the sefer's name was something like 'Matei Efraim' or something similar. (He is not sure that was the name of the sefer)

Did anyone ever come across a sefer, in your decades of learning, which taught that the Dor Ha-Mabul had significant advanced technology? I am looking for that sefer.

Comment: Tiferes yehonasan that migdal bavel was a launchpad for a spaceship? Agav his commentary on Shulchan Aruch is matteh yehonasan

Comment: @robev beat me to it - Rav Yonasan Eibshitz has a whole arichus on this about migdal bovel

Comment: @robev Do you have a weblink to this item? Ty

Comment: @Dov Do you have a weblink to this item? Ty

Comment: It starts here - https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21286&st=&pgnum=21&hilite=